# GLSL Texture Won't Work

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Consider the following:

```
virtual void Draw()
{
    _texture->Bind(0);

    _shader->Begin();
    _shader->SetUniform("WVPMatrix", _mvp);
    _shader->SetUniform("InColor", _color);
    _shader->SetUniformImm("InTexture", 0);
    _vbo.GetDeclaration().Activate();
    _vbo.Render(GL_QUADS, _ibo, 4);
    _shader->End();
}

void Texture2D::Bind(int index)
{
    if (index != -1)
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + index);
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureID);
}
```

Where the calls for _shader->Begin(), _shader->SetUniform, _shader->SetUniformImm, _vbo.GetDeclaration().Activate and _vbo.Render works as if I set the fragment shader to render a static color(or even a color through the uniforms) it renders fine.

Now I'm trying to render a texture2d(it was loaded fine, I tested with immediate mode) and I get a black screen, why?

Vertex:

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 VertexTexCoord;

uniform mat4 WVPMatrix;

out vec2 TexCoord0;

void main()
{
    TexCoord0 = VertexTexCoord;

    gl_Position = WVPMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330

in vec2 TexCoord0;

uniform sampler2D InTexture;
uniform vec4 InColor;

out vec4 OutFragColor;

void main()
{
    OutFragColor = texture(InTexture, TexCoord0) * InColor;
}
```

PS: InColor is white, so it doesn't mess with texture color and TexCoord0 is valid as I already set R and B on OutFragColor as TexCoord0's S and T to debug it values.

Comment: Remembered to [set minification filter](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture) for your texture? Do you do error checking for shader compiling and linking?

Comment: God! I rewrote the texture loading in a more "beautiful" way and forgot to set them -_- 
Thank you

Comment: Careful, I almost deleted my comment after you said it works fine in immediate mode >_>  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Posting answer for bookkeeping)

Question asker forgot to set minification filter for his texture, and as such the texture was not complete and does not display.

Need to call `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);` (or GL_NEAREST)

Comment: shouldn't `GL_MIN_FILTER` be `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`?